# How does one print out the values of an array HORIZONTALLY

Tags: arrays, hash

How does one print out the values of an array stored in a hash in PHP/HTML HORIZONTALLY instead of vertically...??

the code I'm using is a PHP foreach loop inside the body of HTML.

```
    <?php foreach ($config['unsplash_categories'] as $cat): ?>
        <h2><?= $cat ?></h2>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

This prints out my 4 categories vertically instead of horizontally across the screen.

Comment: If the problem is that the `h2`s are one below the other, consider setting their `display` as `inline`.

Comment: That didn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Try using `<h2 style="display:inline;"><?= $cat ?></h2>` instead of `<h2><?= $cat ?></h2>`. Edit: it worked for me.